# javascript object vs reading the document - beginners query on efficiency

Tags: javascript, object

I am creating a web page with some astronomical calculations on which involves the user being able to change date/time/latitude/longitude/etc and the page to recalculate accordingly.

I've created an object - a global one - with a number of properties and methods for updating those properties, but now I am questioning this....

Is it better/more efficient to read the page elements when I need to recalculate, or to have the object constantly in memory.

Here is the object definition:

```
function TIME_OBJ () {

var d = new Date();
//Properties
this.LHour = d.getHours();
this.LMinute = d.getMinutes();
this.LSecond = d.getSeconds();
this.TZone = (d.getTimezoneOffset() / 60) * -1;
this.LDay = d.getDate();
this.LMonth = d.getMonth() + 1;
this.LYear = d.getFullYear();
this.UHours = 0;
this.UMinutes = 0;
this.USeconds = 0;
this.UDay = 0;
this.UMonth = 0;
this.UYear = 0;
this.UTString = "";
this.GSTHour = 0;
this.GSTMinute = 0;
this.GSTSecond = 0;
this.GSTString = "";
this.LSTHour = 0;
this.LSTMinute = 0;
this.LSTSecond = 0;
this.LSTString = "";
this.GDay = 0;
this.GMonth = 0;
this.GYear = 0;
this.GHour = 0;
this.GMinute = 0;
this.GSecond = 0;
this.GString = "";
this.LJD = 0;
this.UJD = 0;
this.LMJD = 0;
this.UMJD = 0;
this.LDoW = 0;
this.UDoW = 0;
this.LDayN = 0;
this.UDayN = 0;
this.LatD = 52;
this.LatM = 0;
this.LatS = 0;
this.LatNS = "S";
this.LatDD = 0;
this.LonD = 0;
this.LonM = 30;
this.LonS = 0;
this.LonEW = "W";
this.LonDD = 0;


//Methods
this.UpdateAll = UpdateAll;
this.UpdateDate = UpdateDate;
this.SetClean = SetTimeClean;
this.GetUT = UpdateUT;
this.GetLJD = UpdateJD;
this.GetUJD = UpdateJD;
this.GetLMJD = UpdateMJD;
this.GetUMJD = UpdateMJD;
this.GetLDoW = UpdateDoW;
this.GetUDoW = UpdateDoW;
this.GetLDayN = UpdateDayN;
this.GetUDayN = UpdateDayN;
this.GetGrDate = UpdateGD;
this.GetGST = UpdateGST;
this.GetLST = UpdateLST;
this.GetDecPos = UpdateDecPos;
this.Dirty = false;
```

}

So, if the date changes this would affect local sidereal time, greenwich time, universal time, sunrise/set, moonrise/set and so on. This would that, if I were reading the page elements, I would have to make many getElementById calls to get the data, as opposed to have a global object with properties already set I just need to page elements once the calculations are complete.

Appreciate your thoughts....
Daz

P.S. is DOM the correct term for the page??

Answer (score 0):

Keeping references in memory is always a lot faster than *searching* the DOM (the elements on the page).  But you could retain references to those elements during the loading of the page and just use those.  It's the traversal of the DOM to find the appropriate elements that's expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the object is HUGELY faster rather than querying the DOM (yep, DOM is correct :-) ), even with getElementByID which is the best way to query.

Also design wise this is better as you could then pass your object to another function as a self-contained bundle instead of having the function re-calc the values from the DOM. This also allows you to write Object oriented code (neater,cleaner code).

Hope this helps.